# In $ZF+ \neg C$ can we always find a bijection from a given set $A$ to a transitive set?

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

Let us write $|A| = |B|$ iff there is a bijection $f \colon A \rightarrow B$. Working in $\operatorname{ZF + \neg C}$, can we prove that for any $A$ there is a transitive $B$ with $|A| = |B|$?

This is trivially true in $\operatorname{ZFC}$, since there is a bijection from $A$ to an ordinal. And in $ZF$, we may apply the Mostowski collapse to obtain such a bijection whenever there is an extensional and transitive relation on $A$. However, I have a feeling that my question might have a negative answer and if so, I'd like to learn a little about its consistency strength (relative to $\operatorname{ZF}$).

Comment: Is it Asaf that I can hear typing right now? ;-)

Comment: While Asaf types, can you illuminate things for the rest of us by saying what $\lnot C$ means here.

Comment: @RobArthan "Assume the negation of the axiom of choice".

Comment: @PatrickStevens: thanks! So the A in AC is annihilated by logical negation $\ddot{\smile}$. That's a new one on me.

Comment: @RobArthan That's not really what it means - it's analogous to $ZFC$, which is a shorthand for $ZF + C$, where $C$ means "the axiom of choice". If we want to use "no choice" instead of "choice", we write $ZF+\neg C$. We lose the A in this context because $ZFAC$ is even weirder than $ZFC$ as a name :)

Comment: @PatrickStevens: my follow-up comment was along the lines of the paper entitled $N = 1$ that purported to prove $P =NP$, except that I wasn't being serious. However, I always refer to the axiom as $AC$ and think of $ZFC$ as an abbreviation for $ZF + AC$ so $C$ as a name for the axiom was new to me.

Comment: It wasn't possible that you heard me this time. While usually I'm on my Unicomp Model M which can probably be heard all the way to Germany, I am actually using my phone right now... :-P

Comment: @Patrick: Also ZFAC is ZFA with choice. :-)

Comment: @Asaf According to my former roommate, my hearing is incredibly sensitive...

Comment: There are too many possible jokes as a followup and I don't want to choose just one. So I'll opt for choosing none.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. For example, an infinite transitive set can be mapped onto $\omega$. So amorphous sets, or other examples of Dedekind finite sets which cannot be mapped onto $\omega$ give you examples of sets which cannot be made transitive.

This can be pushed even further with ease. You could note that an infinite transitive set is in fact Dedekind infinite, thus extending the above example. And you can sit down and notice some of these things actually extend to ordinals larger than $\omega$ to encompass other strange sets.

Comment: Oh, I see. Just mapping each element to its $\in$-rank yields the surjection you claim in your first (- well... second) sentence. As to the sitting down and thinking part - this will get delayed until tomorrow and I might write another comment then. Thanks a lot, Asaf.

Comment: This uses foundation, though...

Comment: @Chappers: Well, not for that answer... But thanks! :-P